# Anyone know of good tutorials for creating an Augmented Reality application from scratch or using an open source framework?

Tags: augmented-reality

I am looking for good tutorials that go through every step of creating an AR application. It would be beneficial if it also covers some of the theory behind optics and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good setup is to use [ARToolKit](http://artoolkit.sourceforge.net/) plus [osgART](http://www.osgart.org).

The tutorial of ARToolKit also explains also some of the principles of Computer Vision:

http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/

osgART is the ARToolKit for [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org) and abstracts some of the principles of using a computer vision based tracking in a scenegraph application

Both toolkits have a large and vibrant development community.

Answer (score 2):

MXRToolkit have good documentation and is suitable for beginner. There are some other toolkits too.

http://mxrtoolkit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Not a trivial learning curve but [OpenScenegraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org) is probably the main FOSS app for large applications like flight simulators.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it but it might be worth looking at: http://developer.qualcomm.com/ar